# Find the continuous variables that most influence an ordinal variable (in R)

Tags: ordinal-data

I have an ordinal variable (range: 1-26) and 32 continuous variables, I have the following problem. Which continuous variable influences the ordinal variable significantly (0.05)?
I tried to use an ordinal regression, I used the "clm" function belonging to the "ordinal" package but I get the following:

Warning message:

(1) Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined 
In addition: Absolute convergence criterion was met, but relative criterion was not met

the summary shows me (this is only a portion of the summary):

```
formula: 
x1 ~ x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + x12 + x13 + x14 + x15 + x16 + x17 + x18 + x19 + x20 + x21 + x22 + x23 + x24 + x25 + x26 + x27 + x28 + x29 + x30 + x31 + x32 + x33
data:    duda

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  40   -0.00  104.00 22(0) 5.42e-09 2.7e+06

Coefficients: (1159 not defined because of singularities)
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
x20,293  -8.358e+01         NA      NA       NA
x20,351  -8.358e+01         NA      NA       NA
x20,381   8.333e+01         NA      NA       NA
x20,476  -1.686e+02         NA      NA       NA
x20,489  -8.358e+01         NA      NA       NA
x20,506  -2.123e+02         NA      NA       NA
x20,539  -7.812e-14         NA      NA       NA
x20,578   2.539e+02         NA      NA       NA
```

What is wrong?
Is there any other way to solve my problem without me using ordinal regression?

Here I show a portion of my data:

```
x1    x2    x3      x4      x5      x6        x7    x8       x9      x10    x11     x12 x13 x14
1   0,688   0,44    0,731   0,478   0,124   0,081   0,311   0,433   0,578   0,337   0,202   0,502   0,321
17  0,879   0,53    0,268   0,502   0,472   0,22    0,252   0,22    0,452   0,356   0,363   0,464   0,427
24  0,75    0,143   0,213   0,479   0,624   0,052   0,272   0,664   0,576   0,176   0,434   0,268   0,504
22  0,775   0,556   0,201   0,354   0,466   0,321   0,228   0,441   0,761   0,71    0,36    0,094   0,614
16  0,659   0,062   0,381   0,543   0,576   0,456   0,407   0,195   0,735   0,176   0,208   0,491   0,143
```

Thankns in advance

Comment: Have read this entry? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230641/clm-function-package-ordinal-hessian-is-numerically-singular-parameters-are-no How many data do you have for the computation and are there `x1` values that are very rare within the dataset? Can you provide `table(duda$x1)`?

Comment: I can convert the 26 levels of X1 into only four levels (normal, mild, moderate, and severe), but I still get a similar result. In total, I have 40 cases.

Comment: I have no experience with `clm` but even with ordinary least squares regression: determination of 32 coefficients (33 with intercept) from just 40 cases is courageous. Assuming the coefficients are determined precisely enough to find significance even more so.